# How to sort a range of Rows up to a certain number of (unknown) columns?

Tags: vba, excel

If I set the initial part of my range as Range("A:A"), how do I make sure the entire row is passed to the sort?

Data
    id, fname, mname, lname, suffix, state, location, timezone

The range is selected by searching id for a starting point and an ending point.
Thus Range might be A1:183 on one sheet and A1:A1138 on another. And the columns end on either G or H. Data still needs "massaging"

On each sheet I'm sorting by D(lname) and B(fname) and I want to include the remaining columns, so the data integrity is preserved.

So far I have a sub that selects the range, but I don't know how to tag on the additional columns without rng.EntireRow.Select, which doesn't seem to be working.

```
Sub sortRows(bodyName As String, ByRef wksht As Worksheet)
Dim operationalRange As Range, sortRange As Range

Set operationalRange = selectBodyRow(bodyName).EntireRow

Debug.Print "Sorting Worksheet " & wksht.Name & " containing " & operationalRange.Count & " rows."
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wksht.Name).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wksht.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=operationalRange, _
      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wksht.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=operationalRange, _
      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wksht.Name).Sort
      .SetRange operationalRange
      .Header = xlGuess
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply   ' Fails here with:
               ' Runtime Error '1004':
               ' The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data
               ' you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the Last Row and and the Last Column to construct your range.

For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this with thee relevant sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Get Last Row and Last Column
    LRow = LastRow(ws)
    LCol = LastColumn(ws)

    With ws
        '~~> Define your range
        Set rng = .Range("A1:" & ReturnName(LCol) & LRow)

        Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Function to get last row
Public Function LastRow(Optional wks As Worksheet) As Long
If wks Is Nothing Then Set wks = ActiveSheet
LastRow = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
    After:=wks.Range("A1"), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function

'~~> Function to get last column
Public Function LastColumn(Optional wks As Worksheet) As Long
If wks Is Nothing Then Set wks = ActiveSheet
LastColumn = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
    After:=wks.Range("A1"), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Column
End Function

'~~> Function to get the Column name from Column Number
Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: Object Variable or With variable not set.

    LastRow = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=wks.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row

Comment: The above code is tried and tested :). Can you show the exact code that you are using?

Comment: This is a good example of finding the last row and last column starting at A1, but what if I am only selecting a particular range between to markers? I know what the row start and row end is, I just want to select the columns. I think I may be able to figure it out from your example.

Comment: `Set rng = .Range("A1:" & ReturnName(LCol) & LRow)` Change `A1` to the relevant start cell.